# Is there a way to prune the gradle cache?

Tags: gradle

On one of our windows build servers we are often getting into a full disk due to gradle cache expansion.  Is there a way to prune this automatically or do I have to delete the cache periodically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle just released this feature: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1085

From version 4.10 onwards, Gradle automatically cleans its user home directory. The cleanup runs in the background when the Gradle daemon is stopped or shuts down. If using --no-daemon, it runs in the foreground after the build session with a visual progress indicator.

See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:gradle_user_home:cache_cleanup

Answer (score 0):

Yes, remove the `$HOME/.gradle` directory assuming that you **do not** store any specific settings in this directory - I mean e.g. in `gradle.properties`

Comment: Thanks Opal, that is what I have been doing.  What I am looking for is a way to either have LRU space limited cache, or a gradle command to go gc.  Does this exist?

Comment: As far as I know such solutions do no exist.

Comment: Solution have just appeared, I've added the answer