# Could not create service of type FileHasher using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createCachingFileHasher()

Tags: gradle, locking, gitlab-ci

## Here is the context of my problem:

- a gitlab ci yml pipeline
- several jobs in the same internship
- all jobs use a task gradle requiring the use of his cache
- all jobs share the same gradle cache

## My problem:

sometimes, when there are several pipelines at the same time, I get :

What went wrong:
Could not create service of type FileHasher using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createCachingFileHasher().

> Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache (/cache/.gradle/caches/5.1/fileHashes). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
>     Owner PID: 149
>     Our PID: 137
>     Owner Operation: 
>     Our operation: 
>     Lock file: /cache/myshop/reunion/.gradle/caches/5.1/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock

I can't find any documentation about the lock system used by gradle. I don't understand why locks are positioned when the gradle action doesn't write to cache dir.

Does anyone know how locks work? Or can I simply change the duration of the timeout to allow concomitant tasks to wait their turn long enough before failing?

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

I tried to tun gradle without a daemon, did not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You typically get this error when trying to share the Gradle cache amongst multiple Gradle processes that run on different hosts. I assume your CI pipelines run on different hosts or they at least run isolated from each other (e.g., as part of different Docker containers).

Unfortunately, such a scenario is [currently not supported](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/851) by Gradle. Gradle developer Stefan Oehme wrote [this comment](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/851#issuecomment-260615203) wrt. sharing the Gradle user home:

> Gradle processes will hold locks if they are uncontended (to gain performance). Contention is announced through inter-process communication, which does not work when the processes are isolated in Docker containers.

And more clearly he states in [a follow-up comment](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/851#issuecomment-260628689) (highlighting by me):

> There might be other issues that we haven't yet discovered though, since **sharing a user home between machines is not a use case we have designed for**.

In other words: sharing a Gradle user home or even just the cache part of it across different machines or otherwise isolated processes is currently not officially supported by Gradle. (See also [my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41704184/1797912).)

I guess the only way to solve this for your scenario is to either:

- make sure that the Gradle processes in your CI pipelines can communicate with each other (e.g., by running them on the same host), or
- don’t directly share the Gradle user home, e.g., by creating copies for all CI pipelines, or
- don’t run the CI pipelines in parallel.

Answer (score 12):

I fixed this by killing all `java` processes in Activity Monitor(MacOS). Hope it helps.

Comment: Exactly!! it only works for me! Actually I restarted the mac without finding all java process and kill those. Lazy!! It started to work.

Answer (score 1):

Another scenario where it could happen is if some of these Gradle related files are on a cloud file system like OneDrive that needs a re-authentication.

1. Re-authenticate to the cloud file system
2. "Invalidate caches and restart" in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

1.First edit your `config file /etc/sysconfig/jenkins` change to root user `JENKINS_USER="root"`

2.Modify `/var/lib/jenkins` file permissions to root `chown -R root:root jenkins`

3.Restart your service `service jenkins restart`

Answer (score 0):

Your Exception:

```
What went wrong: Could not create service of type FileHasher using 
GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createCachingFileHasher().

Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache 
(/cache/.gradle/caches/5.1/fileHashes). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance. 
Owner PID: 149 
Our PID: 137 
Owner Operation: 
Our operation: 
Lock file: /cache/myshop/reunion/.gradle/caches/5.1/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock
```

Thid worked for me:

```
rm /cache/myshop/reunion/.gradle/caches/5.1/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock
```

(Remove the lock file)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using vscode and in windows, seach in the task manager for vscode and the JAVA associated with the gradle should be there. End it and you should be good to go.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).